# Insertar datos desde un DataGridView a SQL en c#, Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

Estoy realizando una aplicación que registra la información diaria de lo que se hizo en una finca durante el día.
El grid muestra algo así. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En donde ocupo ingresar informacion desde el data grid a la base de datos. Pero el tamaño de las filas varia si yo cambio en el combo box la finca. Como se muestra en la imagen. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta seria, como hago para ingresar los datos desde un grid a SQL?

**NOTA: Los nombres de los lotes son efectos de prueba**

Comment: Si estas utilizando la metodologia "four tiers", te recomiendo que al data grid le pases un una lista con la funcion "Datagrid.Datasource"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vas a tener que iterar las rows del grid realizando los INSERT en la tabla, algo como esta estructura

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("<connection string>")) { 
    conn.Open(); 

    string query = "INSERT INTO NombreTabla (campo1, campo2) VALUES (@aram1, @param2)"; 
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn); 


    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) { 
        cmd.Parameters.Clear(); 

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["nombreCol1"].Value)); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["nombrecol2"].Value)); 

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    } 
}
```

como veras cada iteracion del loop asignas parametros al insert tomando estos de las rows del grid

Comment: Eso no afecta que las cantidades de filas varían?

Comment: no porque usas un foreach que itera las Rows

Comment: Muchas Gracias, funciono!